TLB flush during context switch
I am investigating the effects of context switch on linux x86 machines. In particular, I am interested in TLB.
My understanding, after reading Intel Manual 3A (section 4.10.4 "Invalidation of TLBs and Paging-Structure Caches"), is that there is a flush of the TLB non-global entries when there is a change of context.
However, I am not sure if I have understood correctly. Can anyone point me to other references or suggestions on how to prove this?
Thanks in advance

Unless PCIDs are used, an OS must flush the non global entries in the TLB. Otherwise the new process can use the same virtual-to-physical translations of the old one. Leading to a breach of the processes' isolation. You can see that this must be the case by creating a non-PIE program that read an integer and store it in a global variable and then enter a loop that will print that variable every second. Use taskset to pin two instances of this program to the same hardware thread and make them read different value. Each will print its own value, despite using the same virtual address.
